# Find all of the Pure and Mixed Strategy Nash Equilibria

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, probability

When I do the basic calculations for mixed probability, I get that the Column player always plays B. However, I am getting a negative probability for the row. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Question]

Comment: Perhaps there is something wrong with the underlying assumption you are making when you are calculating the mixed Nash equilibrium?

Comment: You are correct that Player 2 always chooses $B$ as it is a dominant strategy. Maybe if you show us the calculations that you made, we can spot the mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are calculating a mixed strategy for the row player so that the column player is indifferent between choosing $A$ and $B$.  And the reason why you get a negative probability is that the row player cannot make the column player indifferent by choosing, say strategy $C$, with a positive probability $\in [0,1]$.  This is because the column player (always) strictly prefers $B$.

> Side-note: To avoid such confusion in the future, try to see whether you can apply math to calculate a mixed strategy to a game.  Here you clearly cannot (because of the above argument), and that is why math is giving you a ''weird'' answer.  Namely, math yields an answer to a question: What would be a **hypothetical** probability with which the row player chooses, say, strategy $C$ to make the column player indifferent?

Answer (score 0):

Hints:

- As you say, B strictly dominates A for the second player.  You can draw a conclusion in terms of Nash equilibria about the second player
- If the second player plays B then C and D produce the same result for the first player.  You can draw a conclusion in terms of Nash equilibria about the first player

If you draw the sensible conclusions, you may be able to see why your calculations for a unique mixed strategy Nash equilibrium is unlikely to work